# Windows Server 2008, can't connect on local SMTP Server into localhost

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, smtp

I can't connect on local SMTP Server into localhost.

It just from external servers.

Firewall Disabled.

The command was "telnet localhost 25".

And the result was: Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 25: Connect failed.

Someone knows the solution?

Comment: I discovered that, for my case, It was caused by antivirus software.

The "Access Protection" from MCAFFEE was blocking the access to SMTP serve locally.

I've disabled It and I've connected.

Comment: Just answer your own question and mark it as an answer - this will help future visitors identifying a relevant solution.

Answer (score 2):

MAke sure to check your antivirus software, it may be denying this connection.